# Monte Carlo Integration of exp(-x^2) from -Infinity to +Infinity

Tags: r, montecarlo

I have to integrate ∫(-∞)^∞〖e^(-x^2 ) dx, I do not know how to tackle the limits and my current result is way off, this is my code:

```
`ok<-function(x) exp(-x^2)
set.seed(999)
n.sim<-10^5
x1<-ok(runif(n.sim))
theta1<-mean(x1)
theta1
[1] 0.7468196 `
```

Comment: Your `runif(n.sim)` only takes on values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify lower and upper limits for `runif()`.  You need to make the limits large enough that it captures the tails of the distribution (the default (0,1) range is definitely not large enough!) but you need to keep it small enough for good coverage. +/- 3 seems reasonable (based on what we already know about the tails of the Normal distribution ...)  You also have to multiply by the size of the domain ...

```
set.seed(101)
mean(exp(-(runif(1e7,-3,3))^2))*6
## [1] 1.771848
```

Compare with `integrate()`:

```
integrate(function(x)exp(-x^2), -3,3)
## 1.772415 with absolute error < 6.4e-11
```

Comment: Thanks that really sums it up, but could you explain why the way i was doing it I needed to multiply by the domain 2 times?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The domain in your example was (0,1) (the default for `runif()`), so its width was only 1, so multiplying by the width of the domain wouldn't have made any difference in that example ...

Comment: I meant to ask: why using the provided code(mine) with the correct domain for the unif dist. I had to multiply by the domain 2 times, but it was a me error I was multiplying by 6 the x not the entire f(x), thanks !